# Why cant operating system decide which program to use when opening files without their suffix?

Tags: security, operating-systems

For example, if we rename a .pdf file to .exe, and try to run it under windows, an error will occur. But is it possible for OS to determine which program to use to open a file based on its content? not just hiding its extension part.

i.e. I have a file named "abc" which is a pdf file. When I double click it, a pdf reader will open.

If it is possible, could there be any security related issues?

Comment: It is possible. And it is done. Just not on windows.

Comment: Its a windows thing. Linux *usually* uses magic numbers to decide what a file is, unless its somehow hardcoded into the software.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: That's _partially_ true, but still wrong enough to become annoying when everyone parrots it without considering e.g. the problems dsolimano has described. Even Windows recognizes executables by the `MZ` magic numbers; even Windows programs allow you to open any file regardless of extension; and even Linux environments rely on the extensions as a quick (if not reliable) indication of what file type it might be. Quite a few system services only accept `.conf` files and reject `.conf.dpkg-new` with identical contents.

Comment: Fine, fixed that for pedantry's sake ;p

Answer (score 4):

It's possible, but not always unambiguously and cleanly.

Take for example Microsoft Office document files (`.docx`, `.xlsx`, etc).  They're really zip files with special contents that Microsoft Office knows how to open.  So if the operating system were to guess based on the file format, it would see that they're valid zip files and open it them up in your compression program.  Unless it first unzipped the files and then started looking at the contents to see if really the files were Excel files, at which point it would delete the temporarily unzipped copy and pass the original file to Excel.  This could possibly be done, but you end up having to have a lot of logic in the OS to make these sorts of guesses.

There are programs which attempt to make this guess - for example, the UNIX program [file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29).  You can look at the [magic numbe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)r page on Wikipedia to get an idea for how this works.  The problem you might run into here is if someone particularly dense used someone else's magic number, you're back to looking at the file extension.  Imagine a non-PDF file format with "%PDF".

Mac OS stored the file type in a special [type code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_code) to get around this problem.

Comment: Add to that OpenDocument files; Java applications; Android packages; Mozilla extensions; Winamp themes...all of which use the Zip format. Not to mention that it's perfectly valid for a Zip file to start in the _middle_, possibly preceded by a self-extractor stub – and if it's called `file.zip` most people certainly would prefer it open in the archiver rather than be executed as a MZ or ELF program...